# Data was truncated on an input, output or update operation

Tags: ftp, unix

**Question**: What can cause that in rare times (**in a few %**), 0 Byte sized files are created over FTP with the following errormessage:

> Data was truncated on an input, output or update operation

**UPDATE**: the mode is "BINARY". The problem still occurs.

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with the BINARY versus ASCII modes. Try the `BIN` command before you upload and see if that resolves the issue. Depending on the FTP client you're using specifying BINARY MODE versus ASCII mode for the transmissions and the defaults may be different. Let me know whether or not this helps you any and if so I will add as an answer.

Comment: Are you by any chance connecting in FTP Active mode ? In that case, the actual data channel is a TCP session opened from the server to the client, which is pretty much guaranteed to fail in any scenario where a firewall is involved. This could potentially result in a 0 byte result, though I would have expected it to end with a timeout error.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish : I updated the question, thanks

Comment: @JeremyGibbons : First, the client tries with passive FTP, then when the error message occurs, it tries with Extended Passive FTP, then it timeouts.

Comment: Where/how exactly you are seeing this "Data was truncated on an input, output or update operation" message?